# Veritysetup Verification fails at hash-offset

Tags: linux, device-mapper, integrity

I'm trying to get dm-verity to verify a sd-card partition. I did

```
veritysetup format --hash-offset=24215552 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sdb4
```

To create a hash device on the same device at the given offset.

Now I want to verify the first 10 data blocks:

```
veritysetup verify --hash-offset=24215552 --data-blocks=10 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sdb4 b49905b65942b0f54a2f70b09cd7bf2c8c15ce6924c7b8bae913ad8cc3f303fc
```

But I get:

```
Verification failed at position 24215552.
Verification of data area failed.
```

I have not the slightest idea why it tries to verify the area where the hash tree should be located since I specified the number of data blocks I want it to verify (and this, in my opinion should stop verification at an offset of 10x1024Bytes). Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After specifying the number of data-blocks in the first command (while creating the hash-tree), it works.

I suppose that if one does not specify the number of data blocks to be hashed, verity hashes the whole device. Then, when it writes the hash tree at the specified offset, the blocks of this section of the disk obviously will change - thus on verification, the hashes previously calculated do not much the data anymore.

So why does it still want to check on this section even if the option "data-blocks" is specified on verification? Because, according to documentation, this option cannot be used on verification, only hash offset and no-superblock can be used. The information about the area to verify must be kept in the header of the hash section when created.